# get user photos by email address using Facebook-api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am working on a new project, and i want to get all user photos in facebook by providing an email address using the facebook graph-api.

I tried to search for some information for how to do it, but with no luck.

Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get photos of a user by authorizing the user with the `user_photos` permission. After that, use the `/me/photos` endpoint. There is no way to get photos (or any data) by email.